# Unix date displayed for ESRI Collector date input?

Tags: arcgis-collector

Trying to set up a date input for a Collector project on iOS, but the app wants dates in 13 digits (I believe Unix or Java time format?). How can I get the input to accept something human-friendly (i.e. m/d/y would be phenomenal).

Comment: can you give an example of a 13 digit date?

Comment: 1463443259392.000000 But it will accept it without the decimal

Comment: Yes it is.  The one with 92 on the end comes from the acceptable date range. When I set up the domain parameters in the geodatabase I put in a normal date (in this case, 5/17/2016) and it gave me that 14634432593 date as one of the date range limits in Collector.

Answer (score 1):

In your ArcGIS Online map, go to your layer's option menu, and select **Configure Pop-up**. In there you'll be able to select your date field and configure how the date/time is displayed and entered:

[image]

This change will propagate to your data entry in Collector.

Comment: Good suggestion, but that still didn't work. I tried several different date formats as well, since googling turned up examples where it made a difference for iOS vs. Android apps. I also checked it on an Android system just to check and it works fine there.

Comment: Where are you hosting your editable data layer, ArcGIS Online or your own ArcGIS Server? The one you see above is hosted on AGOL.

Comment: I am on ArcGIS Online. It looks exactly like your screenshot, but it doesn't make a difference in the app display.